# How to set an endless character Datatype in a Postgres Database table?

Tags: sql, string, postgresql, text, types

I have this database table in postgres:

```
CREATE TABLE dummytable (
     id bigint NOT NULL,
     fieldvalue character varying(255)
)
```

How can i changed the datatype of the field "fieldvalue" to an endless character datatype? Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Use the [text](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-character.html) data type

```
CREATE TABLE dummytable (
     id bigint NOT NULL,
     fieldvalue text
)
```

To alter an existent table

```
alter table dummytable
alter column fieldvalue
set data type text;
```

Comment: Or `varchar` without a length.

Comment: ok thanks, how can i set this field datatype with an sql update statements?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE dummytable ALTER COLUMN fieldvalue TYPE TEXT;
```

For more `ALTER TABLE` option see this link: [PostgreSQL - Alter Table](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html)